# Integral of $\lim{_{n\rightarrow \infty}}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, lebesgue-integral

In an effort to use the Bounded Convergence Theorem, I'd like to show that for a fixed value $M$ that $f_n(x) = \frac{n}{1+n^2x^2} < M$. Taking the derivative, it's clear that 0 is the greatest value of $f_n$ in this interval, but that leaves me with $f_n < n$, where $n$ is not fixed. Any pointers? Can I just fix $x \neq 0$? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: the domain of integration is $[0,1].$

Comment: What is the domain of the integration?

Comment: @user284331 [0,1]. Sorry about that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{n}{1+n^{2}x^{2}}dx&=\int_{0}^{n}\dfrac{1}{1+x^{2}}dx\\
&=\tan^{-1}n\\
&\rightarrow\dfrac{\pi}{2}.
\end{align*}
Bounded Convergence Theorem does not work.

Comment: oh my goodness. I am overlooking things I learned years ago. thanks so much!